# Query returns all the rows

Tags: mysql

Why does this query returns me all the rows matching my `OR LIKE` condition and jumps over `doctorLang`.`city`. What I mean is I get all the rows in all towns not in only certain one.

```
SELECT `doctor`.`id`, `doctorLang`.`first_name`, `doctorLang`.`second_name`, `doctorLang`.`city`, `doctorLang`.`hospital_name`
FROM `doctor` LEFT JOIN `doctorLang` ON `doctor`.`id`=`doctorLang`.`doc_id`
WHERE `doctorLang`.`city`='Пловдив' 
AND `doctorLang`.`language`='bg' 
AND `doctor`.`active`=1
AND `doctorLang`.`first_name` LIKE '%йло'
OR `doctorLang`.`first_name` LIKE '%йло%'
OR `doctorLang`.`first_name` LIKE 'йло%'
OR `doctorLang`.`second_name` LIKE '%йло'
OR `doctorLang`.`second_name` LIKE '%йло%'
OR `doctorLang`.`second_name` LIKE 'йло%'
OR `doctorLang`.`third_name` LIKE '%йло'
OR `doctorLang`.`third_name` LIKE '%йло%'
```

Comment: Provide your sample input?output...

Comment: Because you didn't use parantheses. Classical mistake.

Comment: The [`AND` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html) has higher precedence than the [`OR` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html). Blame the maths for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version of your `WHERE` clause which should behave as expected:

```
WHERE
    doctorLang.city = 'Пловдив' AND
    doctorLang.language = 'bg'  AND
    doctor.active = 1           AND
    (
        doctorLang.first_name LIKE '%йло'   OR
        doctorLang.first_name LIKE '%йло%'  OR
        doctorLang.first_name LIKE 'йло%'   OR
        doctorLang.second_name LIKE '%йло'  OR
        doctorLang.second_name LIKE '%йло%' OR
        doctorLang.second_name LIKE 'йло%'  OR
        doctorLang.third_name  LIKE '%йло'  OR
        doctorLang.third_name LIKE '%йло%'
    )
```

Your original `WHERE` clause, without parentheses, was being interpreted as this:

```
WHERE
    (
        doctorLang.city = 'Пловдив' AND
        doctorLang.language = 'bg'  AND
        doctor.active = 1           AND
        doctorLang.first_name LIKE '%йло'
    )
    OR
        doctorLang.first_name LIKE '%йло%'  OR
        doctorLang.first_name LIKE 'йло%'   OR
        ...
```

In other words, if even one of the `OR` conditions involving the name were true, it would cause all rows to be returned, apparently ignoring your other restrictions.

The take home lesson here is that `AND` has higher *precedence*, or order of execution, than `OR`.  But we can impose any evaluation order we want by using parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

It is working for an or condition actually
its like 
city='something'
or 
name='something'

use a subquery instead

first fetch for the town you are looking for and then from that result for the names you are looking for

hope it helps